# Rails HABTM checkboxes don't save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many, railscasts

I am beginning Rails programming and all I want to accomplish is to have a list of check boxes from which I can choose the corresponding categories for a product.
I have followed the railscast on this matter, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I work with Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.7.

I have the models properly set up and the migration for the join table as well.
When I try to edit a product, the category_ids get POSTed, but they are never saved to the database.

Log :

```
Started POST "/products/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Sep 19 01:39:33 +0300 2011
  Processing by ProductsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Product",     "authenticity_token"=>"x2Z5GGiNh9yLz6xjuQaMqdGW3Gw7dYe8dSghyrFpiYk=", "utf8"=>"���", "id"=>"1", "product"=>{"name"=>"Magicianulx2", "price"=>"121", "category_ids"=>["1"]}}
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_ids
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/1
Completed 302 Found in 10ms


Started GET "/products/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Sep 19 01:39:33 +0300 2011
  Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 6.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Models :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Migration :

```
class AddCategoriesProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_products, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :product_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories_products
  end
end
```

Controller (update method in product controller)

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
      redirect_to @product, :notice  => "Successfully updated product."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

My _form.html.erb in views/products

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>

<% for category in Category.find(:all) %>
        <div>
                <%= check_box_tag "product[category_ids][]", category.id, @product.categories.include?(category) %>
                <%= category.name %>
        </div>
   <% end %>

<p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

The controllers and the views were all generated using nifty scaffolding.
Everything else seems to work just fine, but the values from the check boxes don't get saved to the database.
Adding them by hand via the rails console works just fine.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Product model has `attr_accessible :name, :price` and that's why the log shows `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_ids` when you try to do `@product.update_attributes(params[:product])` in your controller.

Try adding `category_ids` to `attr_accessible`.

Comment: @James, if you get bored, take a look at my blog post and tell me why I didn't need the `attr_accessible`, 'cuz it's been bugging me, and I haven't had a chance to revisit it :/

Answer (score 0):

When I did more or less the same thing, my `check_box_tag` looked different:

```
<%= check_box_tag :category_ids,  
                  cat.id,  
                  @product.categories.include?(cat),  
                  :name => 'product[category_ids][]' %>
```

I ended up *not* needing the `attr_accessible`, although as I mention in [my blog post describing the exact same thing](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/08/associating-hasmany-relationships-in.html), I'm still not sure why not. I also used `has_many:through`.